# How to redirect multiple domains to woocommerce product page dynamically?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, dns

Consider **abc.com** is my main website using nameservers **ns1.testnameserver.com** & **ns2.testnameserver.com**.

I would like to redirect multiple domains as below:

```
def.com to abc.com/products/def
ghi.com to abc.com/products/ghi
jkl.com to abc.com/products/jkl
mno.com to abc.com/products/mno
```

*I tried the below:*

i set the same testnameserver for def.com,ghi.com,jkl.com,mno.com.

tried some combination in **RewriteCond** and **.htaccess** but i couldn't solve it.

Anyone guide me to move further.

Thanks all.

Note:

I can't use domain forwarding / host all the domains because it's should be dynamic (like 3500+ domains to 3500+ products)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, but you can redirect domains with:

```
RewriteEngine on 
# not for exemple.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:^|\.)([^.]+)\.(?:[^.]+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/products/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L]
```

Point all your DNS on the main website, and just change the name of the main domain (example.com) in this .htaccess

Comment: i am using shared hosting for the main website, so should i use the same nameserver for all the domains that to be forward?!

Comment: Yes you can ! But the most important thing is that they all point to the same place.

Comment: How to do for the .net, .org, .co domains? 

Is the below code is enough?

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example\.co$ [NC]

Comment: No. You can use: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example\.(?:com|net|org|co)$ [NC]`

Comment: is there anyway to avoid SSL warning error? i have SSL for my main website but not for all 3500+ domains :(

Comment: Not with a redirect

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using below steps -

1. You need to setup the zone file for each domain having an A record entry pointing to IP address of abc.com.
2. On abc.com web server, you can write an script in any language of your choice which will read the host and appropriately does a redirect to wherever you need.

Alternatively you could do this from .htacess too, but since you have a large amount of domains, so I would suggest to go with a script in any language (php, python etc.)

Comment: Live example: Efty.com using ns1.efty.com & ns2.efty.com. All the domains using these nameservers will forward to it's own product pages dynamically. movingup.com & seodirector.com is using these nameservers in live.

Comment: You can achieve this using name servers as well, but for that you need to setup your own name server e.g. bind etc and have to program the name server accordingly. Just setting up a forwarding dns wouldn’t be enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can do exactly what you are looking for with a `RewriteMap` directive.

First place your mappings in a file, e.g. `/var/lib/domains.txt` containing

```
def.com     http://example.net/products/def
ghi.com     http://example.net/products/ghi
jkl.com     http://example.net/products/jkl
mno.com     http://example.net/products/mno
```

Then you set up the following rules in a server or virtual host `.conf` -file (you **cannot** do this in a .htaccess file):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteMap      lowercase       int:tolower
RewriteMap      custdomains     txt:/var/lib/domains.txt

# rewrite matching domain to desired URL
RewriteCond     ${lowercase:%{HTTP_HOST}}       ^(?:www\.)?(.+)
RewriteCond     ${custdomains:%1}               ^(.+)$
RewriteRule     ^/(.*)$                         %1              [R=301,L,NE]

# unmatched domains are passed unchanged
RewriteRule     .                               -               [R,NE,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` -rules will capture the HTTP_HOST header containing the hostname of the target domain the user is browsing to. If that hostname matches a mapping defined in your textfile, the browser will be redirected to the matching URL.

With this setup you can point all your thousands of domains to the same server, which then performs suitable redirects based on the mappings in an external file (which you can update without having to restart apache). For better performance, you should really use an external DBM Hash File instead (see the documentation for `RewriteMap` for details).